# Ramsey cardinals lemma

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals, infinitary-combinatorics

I am reading the chapter on large cardinals in Jech's book and I found the following lemma:

> If $\kappa \rightarrow (\kappa)^{<\omega} $ and if $\lambda < \kappa $ is a cardinal, then $ \kappa \rightarrow (\kappa)^{<\omega}_\lambda $.
>
> Proof. Let $ F:[\kappa]^{<\omega} \rightarrow \lambda $ be a partition $ \lambda < \kappa $ pieces. We consider the following partition $G$ of $[\kappa]^{<\omega}$ into two pieces: If $\alpha_1 < . . . < \alpha_k < α_{k+1} <. . . < \alpha_{2k} $ are elements of $ \kappa$ and if $F({\alpha_1, . . . , \alpha_k}) = F({\alpha_{k+1}, . . . , \alpha_{2k}})$, then we let $G({\alpha_1, . . . , \alpha_{2k}}) = 1$; for all other $x \in [\kappa]^{<\omega}$, we let $G(x) = 0$.
> Now, let $H \subset \kappa$ be a homogeneous set for $G$, $|H| = \kappa$. We claim that for each $k$ and each $x \in [H]^{2k}$, $G(x) = 1$: This is because $|H| = \kappa > \lambda$, and therefore we can find $\alpha_1 < . . . < \alpha_k < \alpha_{k+1} < . . . < \alpha_{2k}$ in $H$ such that $F({\alpha_1, . . . , \alpha_k}) = F({\alpha_{k+1}, . . . , \alpha_{2k}})$.

My question is why the last argument is valid? I don't understand why $G$ gets $1$ on $H$ and not $0$ even when fixing the problem with definition of $G$ to be only on the even numbers.

Comment: What is “the problem with the definition of $G$ to be on the even numbers”? I don’t see a problem with what’s written and maybe that is part of the confusion. The last sentence shows by pigeonhole that $G$ must be one on *some* sequence in $[H]^{2k},$ and since $H$ is homogeneous for $G$, this means it must be so for all. (Also, there’s a bit more to show to get the theorem after this, but I’m assuming you just stopped at the part where you were confused.)

Comment: I don't understand why it needs to be 1 for some sequences in $[H]^{2k}$. Yes I have stop where I didn't understand.

Comment: You are right, I was wrong with the problem in the definition.

Comment: It’s a pigeonhole argument. Consider a subset of $[H]^k$ of size $\kappa$ where none of the sequences overlap. The fact that $F$ only takes $\lambda<\kappa$ possible values means that it must take the same value on two of these sequences.

Comment: And why is the intersection not trivial?

Comment: what intersection?

Comment: Do you mean why does a set of the sort I describe in my second sentence exist? Let $A_0$ be the first $k$ elements of $H$ in its increasing enumeration, then let $A_1$ be the next $k$ elements, etc. $\{A_\alpha:\alpha<\kappa\}$ will match my description..

Comment: Oh I see what you did, you took a slight modification of $[H]^k$, seems good thanks!